# Example of Complex Closure, Interior and Boundary

Tags: complex-analysis

I came up with a problem in Alphors that asks the following:
Given $X$ as the set of complex numbers with real and imaginary parts rational, what is, the Interior, the Bounday and the Closure.

If possible I would like examples to add, like other sets also, to comprehend better.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here.

Comment: I think it's very clear indeed.

Comment: The topology on $\mathbb C$ turns out to be the same as in $\mathbb R^2$. Does this help?

Comment: @JoãoVíctorMelo I would say it isn't clear what you're asking. Also, I think you mean Ahlfors, not Alphors.

Comment: It depends what clear is to us both isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we consider the subset $X=\mathbb{Q}+i\mathbb{Q}\subseteq\mathbb{C}$, where $\mathbb{C}$ is equipped with the *[standard topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_topology)*.

- We know that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ which means that the closure $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}=\mathbb{R}$.
  Similarly we have here the closure of  $\mathbb{Q}+i\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{C}$.
  \begin{align*}
  \color{blue}{\overline{\mathbb{Q}+i\mathbb{Q}}=\mathbb{C}}
  \end{align*}
- We observe that for any point $z\in\mathbb{Q}+i\mathbb{Q}$ and any positive real number $r>0$ the ball $B(z;r)$ with center $z$ and radius $r$ contains points from $\mathbb{Q}+i\mathbb{Q}$ as well as points from the complement $\mathbb{C}\setminus\left(\mathbb{Q}+i\mathbb{Q}\right)$. This means the set is equal with its boundary.
  \begin{align*}
  \color{blue}{\mathbb{Q}+i\mathbb{Q}=\partial\left(\mathbb{Q}+i\mathbb{Q}\right)}
  \end{align*}
- It follows that there are no interior points in $\mathbb{Q}+i\mathbb{Q}$:
  \begin{align*}
  \color{blue}{\left(\mathbb{Q}+i\mathbb{Q}\right)^{\circ}=\emptyset}
  \end{align*}